# Different values of a static const member of a template struct

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm trying to make a small metaprogramming struct that generates a bit mask of `width` bits shifted `shift` positions to the left (for learning purposes mostly). The following code triggers warning C4293 (shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior) on VC++15 for `mask<64>::value;`,  because it still triggers the second branch of the ternary operator - even though it's not supposed to affect the value itself. What would be a better, cleaner way to achieve this?

```
// Bitmask of 'width' bits shifted 'shift' bits to the left
// For instance, mask<16,8> := 0x00FFFF00 
template <uint8_t width, uint8_t shift=0>
struct mask {
    static const uintmax_t value = (width >= (sizeof(uintmax_t)<<3)) ?
            (~0 << shift) : (((uintmax_t(1)<<width)-1) << shift) ;
    mask()=delete;
};

// A bitmask for a type, for instance, 0xFF for uint8_t
template <class T>
struct typeMask {
    static const uintmax_t value = mask<sizeof(T)<<3>::value;
    typeMask()=delete;
};
```

Comment: The actual error message is more useful information than "C4293". Very few people memorise the error codes from VC++.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to put it but forgot in the end. Fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid ever compiling the redundant branch of the condition
`width >= (sizeof(uintmax_t)<<3)`. I only have gcc 5.1 and and clang 3.6 at my 
disposal but I expect VC++2015 also will let you do it like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <uint8_t width, uint8_t shift=0, typename Enable = void>
struct mask;

template <uint8_t width, uint8_t shift> struct 
mask<width,shift,typename std::enable_if<(width >= (sizeof(uintmax_t)<<3))>::type> 
{
    static const uintmax_t value = (~0 << shift);
    mask()=delete;
};

template <uint8_t width, uint8_t shift> struct 
mask<width,shift,typename std::enable_if<(width < (sizeof(uintmax_t)<<3))>::type> 
{
    static const uintmax_t value = (((uintmax_t(1)<<width)-1) << shift);
    mask()=delete;
};

template <class T>
struct typeMask {
    static const uintmax_t value = mask<sizeof(T)<<3>::value;
    typeMask()=delete;
};
```

Incidentally, compiling `mask<64>::value`, clang complains:

```
warning: in-class initializer for static data member is not a constant expression; folding it to a constant is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]
static const uintmax_t value = (~0 << shift);
                               ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

You can correct what it is complaining of by replacing `~0` with `~uintmax_t(0)`.